# img slidershow jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I need help with my img slider, i found a jquery slider with name "parallax content slider" and they have tutorial that dont work in my website! the link for the plug in

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

```
<link href="Content/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/style2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/js/modernizr.custom.28468.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js/jquery.cslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">

<div class="da-slide">
    <h2>Some headline</h2>
    <p>Some description</p>
    <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
    <div class="da-img">
        <img src="../Images/images/1.png" alt="image01" />
    </div>

   <div class="da-slide">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->

<nav class="da-arrows">
    <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
    <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
</nav>
```

**Example:**

[jsfiddle.net/njyEL/2](http://jsfiddle.net/njyEL/2)

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: i cant see the img, h2, p or a link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/njyEL/2/

Comment: one more thing, the javascript dont work either